# Loop through different dataframes and perform actions using a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

I have 10 dataframes that have the same structure (same number of rows and columns) and I am trying to find an efficient way of performing several actions such as renaming columns with a for loop. I have tried putting them in a list such as

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
for i in dfs:
    i.rename(columns={'A': 'a1'},inplace=True)
```

but it doesn't work. Another issue occurs if I try to use a function and then loop such as:

```
def groupdfs(anydf)
    anydf = anydf.groupby("A").sum

for i in dfs:
    groupdfs(i)
```

No changes are happening to the dataframes. I have searched similar old questions but nothing have worked. What is the best way to loop through many dataframes when you want to perform the same changes to each of them?

Comment: Are you sure your first block doesn't work? It normally would work I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code you wrote should work fine.

```
data = np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)])
dff = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c', 'a', 'b'])

dff

    c   a   b
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9

dato = np.array([(11, 12, 13), (41, 15, 16), (17, 18, 9)])
dfg = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['c', 'a', 'b'])

dfg

    c   a   b
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9

dffs = [dff, dfg]
for i in dffs:
    i.rename(columns={'a': 'a1'},inplace=True)

    c   a1  b
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9

The only thing I can think of is that you should add a line in the end to save changes to files.
```

Comment: when I do the loop in your example, and I run dff the column name hasn't changed. Its like the changes aren't saved as you mentioned. How would I do the saving at the end?

Comment: @Sotomayor1989 if you followed all of my steps, you should have the same result. Most likely its something to do with naming your files or columns. By saving I meant saving the changes back to your files, pandas data frames should allow you to see the results

Comment: You are actually right. I can verify that when I use inplace=True it does perform the change. but if I want to slice the dataframe such as: 
for i in dfs: 
     i = i[["a","b"]]

then the new changes are not saved.

Comment: @Sotomayor1989 you don't need to slice anything since you're only replacing names in specific columns. Try using the code as is with inputting column names

Answer (score 0):

#### For the first part

Since everything is the same, you can create a list with new column names and assign it to all of them like this:

```py
column_names = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df.columns = column_names
```

Or, if you want to use dictionary to change some columns only you can:

```py
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df.rename({'A':'a1'}, axis=1, inplace = True)
```

Note that `axis = 1` stands for columns level

#### For the second part

There are two issues:

1. The `groupby` creates a new DataFrame that has to be assigned to a variable if you want to use it again
2. Since you are in a function, you have to return that new DataFrame to be assigned to a variable outside the function as below:

```py
def groupdfs(anydf)
    return anydf.groupby("A").sum()

for i in dfs:
    i = groupdfs(i)
```

This will replace the old DataFrame with the new groupby one. It's better to create new variables for the new groupby dataframes

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding the first part, if I want to do another action such as slicing the existing dataframes to smaller dataframes then it seems that the changes are not saved.

 if I want to slice the dataframe such as: 
for i in dfs: i = i[["a","b"]] then the new changes are not saved.