# Iterate through different dataframes and apply a function to each one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, for-loop

I have 4 different dataframes containing time series data that all have the same structure.

My goal is to take each individual dataframe and pass it through a function I have defined that will group them by datestamp, sum the columns and return a new dataframe with the columns I want. So in total I want 4 new dataframes that have only the data I want.

I just looked through this post:
[Loop through different dataframes and perform actions using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311090/loop-through-different-dataframes-and-perform-actions-using-a-function)
but applying this did not change my results.

Here is my code:

I am putting the dataframes in a list so I can iterate through them

```
dfs = [vds, vds2, vds3, vds4]
```

This is my function I want to pass each dataframe through:

```
def VDS_pre(df):
    df = df.groupby(['datestamp','timestamp']).sum().reset_index()
    df = df.rename(columns={'datestamp': 'Date','timestamp':'Time','det_vol': 'VolumeVDS'})
    df = df[['Date','Time','VolumeVDS']]
    
    return df
```

This is the loop I made to iterate through my dataframe list and pass each one through my function:

```
for df in dfs:
    df = VDS_pre(df)
```

However once I go through my loop and go to print out the dataframes, they have not been modified and look like they initially did. Thanks for the help!

Comment: use list comprehension:  `[VDS_pre(df) for df in dfs]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*However once I go through my loop and go to print out the dataframes, they have not been modified and look like they initially did.*

Yes, this is actually the case. The reason why they have not been modified is:

**Assignment to an `item` in a `for item in lst:` loop does not have any effect on both the `lst` and the identifier/variables from which the `lst` items got their values** as it is demonstrated with following code:

```
v1=1; v2=2; v3=3
lst = [v1,v2,v3]
for item in lst:
    item = 0
print(lst, v1, v2, v3) # gives: [1, 2, 3] 1 2 3
```

To achieve the result you expect to obtain you can use a list comprehension and the list unpacking feature of Python:

```
vds,vds2,vds3,vds4=[VDS_pre(df) for df in [vds,vds2,vds3,vds4]]
```

or following code which is using a list of strings with the identifier/variable names of the dataframes:

```
sdfs = ['vds', 'vds2', 'vds3', 'vds4']
for sdf in sdfs:
    exec(str(f'{sdf} = VDS_pre(eval(sdf))'))
```

Now printing `vds`, `vds2`, `vds3` and `vds4` will output the modified dataframes.

Comment: List comprehension solved my issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas frame operations return new copy of data. Your snippet store the result in `df` variable which is not stored or updated to your initial list. This is why you don't have any stored result after execution.

If you don't need to keep original frames, you may simply overwrite them:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    dfs[i] = VDS_pre(df)
```

If not just use a second list and append result to it.

```
l = []
for df in dfs:
    df2 = VDS_pre(df)
    l.append(df2)
```

Or even better use list comprehension to rewrite this snippet into a single line of code.

Now you are able to store the result of your processing.

Additionally if your frames have the same structure and can be merged as a single frame, you may consider to first `concat` them and then `apply` your function on it. That would be totally pandas.